# How can we achieve this view in swift?

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

[image][image]

Any guideline regarding this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Cay you be more specific what part of this above screen you need to design.

Comment: last part of the image. when down arrow is clicked,  it hides and on click, it shows up.

Answer (score 3):

I would look into [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview). You would need to use the `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` to fit 4 items per width of the screen. It looks to be a `UICollectionView` that is anchored above a [UIToolBar](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitoolbar) perhaps both the `UICollectionView` and `UIToolbar` are embedded within a [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview). Play around with an empty project and try to put it together.

Comment: Okay. I will try to do that. what about pager at the end?

Comment: You can use a simple page control to show the page indicators.